# LIBXML attribute element value matching

Tags: perl, xpath, libxml2

I have simple findnodes where I just want to match the attribute measValue from

```
< measValue measObjLdn='XYZ' >
```

from my XML

```
findnodes(/measValue[@measObjLdn='XYZ')])
```

I get Error as `Global symbol "@measObjLdn" requires explicit package name`

and when I scape the @ then I get the error `XPath error : Invalid predicate`

```
findnodes(/measValue[\@measObjLdn='XYZ')])
```

Also when I make measValue  and measObjLdn as variables then its even worse

```
my $mv=measValue;

my $mn=measObjLdn;

findnodes(/$mv["\@". "$mn"='XYZ')])
```

Any solution for this would be appreciated.

Comment: You should pay more attention to the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/lib/XML/LibXML/XPathContext.pod). You'll see that all of the examples of XPath expressions are quoted strings.

Answer (score 3):

Your XPath should be in a string:

```
$xml->findnodes( "/measValue[\@measObjLdn='XYZ')]" )
```

Comment: And if you put it in a single-quoted strring, you don't even have to escape the `@` :-)

Comment: Indeed, but that would just complicate the "when I make measValue and measObjLdn as variables" part.